# difference between '==' and '===' in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

> i have also read from this link
>     https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html
>
> but i didn't understand can anyone give me example with proper clarification!!

i mean if we do:

```
val str1 = "Hello, World!"
val str2 = "Hello," + " World!"
println(str1 == str2)//print true
println(str1 === str2)//also print true
```

so whats the difference between them??

Comment: `===` is referential equality which checks whether the objects are pointing to same locations or not. `==` checks for values

Comment: i know about php but in kotlin not understand...if the check objects are pointing to same location or not so how can test this case

Comment: Refer this link http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-equality-operators

Comment: @NikolaLukic It's not checking _type_ . It's checking reference equality.

Comment: In your case, the JVM decides (correctly) that you are creating two copies of the same String, so it just uses one. That's why `===` is true when you are actually trying to create two different String objects.

Comment: How can we get == false and for === true ? Or any way to get different bool

Comment: You could have `var b = "H"+a.substring(1);`. That will produce a different object with the same content.

Comment: no i checked it ...result also same 'true'

Comment: @JatinBansal Worked when I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in concepts of equality. "==" checks structural equality (same value), "===" checks referential equality (same place in memory).

Comment: ya i know this theory tom, can you give me any example of '==' type

Comment: So if you got two different objects but with the same values, if you use "==" it will compare only value of both. If you use "===" it will return false, becouse those objects are in different place in memory.